# I get no multithreading when compiling for release mode

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, eigen

I am programming a matrix-matrix multiplication using the Eigen library in VS2010.  When I run in debug mode the application uses all my CPU, but when I run in release mode it uses only 1 thread.  Is there a setting I need to change in order to enable multi-threading?

Comment: Odd... seems backwards. How have you verified both behaviors?

Comment: @Andrew Barber, using the taskmanager in windows 7.

Comment: taskmanager does not show threads !!!

Comment: Well it does to me under "performance">"resource Monitor"...

Comment: Add your edit as an answer and accept it as the right answer so others can find it if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is so silly but i never enabled openMP for RELEASE mode in properties configuration even though i thought i did.

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your solution.  Cheers~